# Using GSL with cygwin g++

Tags: cygwin, g++

trying to get the Gnu Scientific Library (gsl) to work in cygwin g++.

Cygwin is installed and updated with all default parameters and includes gsl:runtime, gsl-apps and gsl-doc. I am trying the example program given in the gsl website:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/An-Example-Program.html

## include

```
 #include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
 int
 main (void)
 {
   double x = 5.0;
   double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
   printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
   return 0;
 }
```

Would anyone be so kind as to give me a version of the above program that actually works with g++? The header file is nowhere to be found with this default installation. How do I access the dll?

I also tried to install the non-default 'gsd-devel' (the developper tools), which gives me access to the header file but when I compile I am getting "Undefined reference to 'gsl__sf_bessel_J0'", even though the header file is found.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I am new to CygWin & GSL as well, and I after some research, I think the answer lies in the fact that the required libraries are not being linked. There is a clever little tool which comes with GSL called `gsl-config`. You can use this to get the linking information to the libraries. So in your case, the code:

```
 #include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 int
 main (void)
 {
   double x = 5.0;
   double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
   printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
   return 0;
 }
```

can be compiled using `g++ bessel.cpp -lm -lgsl -o bessel.out -L/usr/bin` where the `-lm -lgsl -L/usr/bin` bit is the output of typing  `gsl-config --lib-without-cblas`. Test using `./bessel.out`.

Hope this helps, T