# Getting the Gnu Scientific Library to work in Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin, gsl

I'm using gsl and Cygwin, and to get started I am trying to compile a very simple program (which I will later call from a Fortran program). I am unable to get it compile due to problems locating the the gsl files. The code is:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>

void gslgateway_(double *x, double *res){
   *res = gsl_atanh(*x);
}
```

When I try to compile it by:

```
gcc -c gslgateway.c
```

I get the following error:

```
gslgateway.c:1:26: error: gsl/gsl_math.h: No such file or directory
```

If I change the first line to

```
#include <C:/cygwin/usr/include/gsl/gsl_math.h>
```

then gsl_math.h is found, but a bunch of other files are not:

```
In file included from gslgateway.c:1:
C:/cygwin/usr/include/gsl/gsl_math.h:23:25: error: gsl/gsl_sys.h: No such file or directory
...
```

So, the problem seems to be the path to the library files. But try as I might, I can't seem to set this correctly. I used gsl-config as suggested at  [Using GSL with cygwin g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529509/using-gsl-with-cygwin-g) and it gives me

```
-L/usr/include
```

so I tried compiling using that as an option, but I get the same result. I've also tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/lib, /usr/include, C:/cygwin/usr/include and several other combinations but nothing works.

I don't know what else to try now. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

(Other info: I have gsl-devel installed. At least, I asked the Cygwin Installer to install it, and I can find a folder /usr/include/gsl that contains gsl_math.h amongst many other files. I don't know if there's anything else I need to do there.)

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If you're using MinGW, it won't know how to interpret Cygwin-style paths.

Comment: That probably explains it. I only installed Cygwin today, but already had MinGW. After restarting Cygwin, things seem to be working. I checked 'gcc -v' and the target is 'i686-pc-cygwin'. (when I check it in the Windows command line, it's 'i686-w64-mingw') Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my guess appears to have been correct, I'll post it as an answer.

It looks like you're using the MinGW compiler.  MinGW isn't part of Cygwin, so it doesn't understand Cygwin-style paths.  That's why your compiler was able to find `C:/cygwin/usr/include/` but not `/usr/include`.