# Using GSL with MinGW on Windows

Tags: windows, g++, mingw, gsl

I got GSL to work using CygWin as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529509/using-gsl-with-cygwin-g), but I'd like to produce an executable using  MinGW. I downloaded GnuWin32, and I got rid of a few errors by putting the contents of GnuWin32\include into MinGW\include, and doing the same for the lib and bin directories, but I'm still getting the error,

```
undefined reference to 'gsl_sf_bessel_J0'
```

The code I'm trying to run is,

```
#include <gsl\gsl_sf_bessel.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  double x = 5.0 ;
  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0( x ) ;
  printf( "J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y ) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

I learned from [here](http://sourceware.org/ml/gsl-discuss/2003-q3/msg00268.html) that the linker produced this error message, but I'm not sure what do with this information. I imagine that I need to add some things to compilation command, but I'm not sure what to add. Right now I'm trying to compile using the command,

```
g++ gsltest.cpp -o gsltest.exe
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geez, Louise. I figured it out. Use,

```
g++ gsltest.cpp -o gsltest.exe -lgsl -lm
```

More information can be found using [this](http://www.udel.edu/it/research/training/scientific_programming_I/Scientific-Programming-I-UNIX.pdf) powerpoint on scientific programming.