# Where is GSL installed on cygwin, windows 10?

Tags: cygwin, gsl

I want to use GSL on Windows 10. After I install GSL packages in cygwin, I cannot find the install gsl folder under cygwin. The error is like this:

$ g++ bessel.cpp -lm -lgsl -o bessel.out -L/usr/bin
bessel.cpp:1:32: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

though I do see the GSL packages installed:

[image]

I've followed below link on a small test .cpp file.
[Using GSL with cygwin g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529509/using-gsl-with-cygwin-g)

Please help me on gsl library setup in Windows 10.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know where the files are and if the package are installed.
Check wich package contains "gsl" in the name

```
$ cygcheck -cd |grep gsl
gsl                                     2.3-2
gsl-apps                                2.3-2
gsl-devel                               2.3-2
gsl-doc                                 2.3-2
libgsl-devel                            2.3-2
libgsl0                                 1.16-2
libgsl19                                2.3-2
```

The headers and import libraries for compilation are in devel packages.
We check the package status:

```
$ cygcheck -c libgsl-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
libgsl-devel         2.3-2          OK
```

So the package is correclti installed and no files are missing.
List the package contents

```
$ cygcheck -l libgsl-devel
/usr/bin/gsl-config
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_blas.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_blas_types.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_block.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_block_char.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_block_complex_double.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_block_complex_float.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_block_complex_long_double.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_block_double.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_block_float.h
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_block_int.h
[cut]
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_wavelet2d.h
/usr/lib/libgsl.dll.a
/usr/lib/libgslcblas.dll.a
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/gsl.pc
/usr/share/aclocal/gsl.m4
/usr/share/info/gsl-ref.info-1.gz
/usr/share/info/gsl-ref.info-2.gz
/usr/share/info/gsl-ref.info-3.gz
/usr/share/info/gsl-ref.info-4.gz
/usr/share/info/gsl-ref.info-5.gz
/usr/share/info/gsl-ref.info-6.gz
/usr/share/info/gsl-ref.info.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gsl-config.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/gsl.3.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

If the installation directory for Cygwin is `C:\cygwin64`, then the header file you reference above is located at the following location:

```
C:\cygwin64\usr\include\gsl\gsl_sf_bessel.h
```

If you do not see it there, you may need to reinstall the `gsl` and `libgsl-devel` packages from your Cygwin installation program.  The code provided on the [Using GSL with cygwin g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529509/using-gsl-with-cygwin-g) page should compile fine as long as you add the `stdio.h` header file to the source code, as shown in the answer on that page:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    double x = 5.0;
    double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
    printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming this file is `bessel.cpp`, it should compile with:

```
g++ bessel.cpp -lgsl
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your quick answer. I've check the path. It is found that there is no gsl folder under C:\cygwin64\usr\include\.  It looks like there is a problem installing GSL with cygwin64. As shown in the picture, I did have a few gsl libraries options checked when install it. What could be wrong to a successfully install gsl with cygwin? I mean, it gsl libraries are installed, its header files should be in the folder as you show, right?

Comment: @RobertWilliam - Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling the gsl packages on Cygwin?  I installed the gsl package first (and its dependencies) but the headers were not installed in that step.  I then installed libgsl-devel and they appeared.  Perhaps an installation glitch?  Or try with another mirror?  (That one is probably a stretch... just throwing out ideas now.)  Let me know if there are other files you'd like me to look up in my local installation for you.  I have the 64-bit version of Cygwin running on Windows 10.

Comment: As a more general answer, you might also want to note that you can find where any Cygwin package is installed by searching https://cygwin.com/packages/.